# How to change android keyboard key font?

Tags: android, fonts, keyboard

How can I change the default font for keys of keyboard I am writing in android (Eclipse)?
Thank you

Comment: Are you looking for a keyboard theme?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an answer : Implemented onDraw...

```
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
    // super.onDraw(canvas) // commented not to draw default keyboard
    if (!isInEditMode) {
        onBufferDraw()
        if (mBuffer != null)
            canvas.drawBitmap(mBuffer!!, 0f, 0f, null)
    }
}

private fun onBufferDraw() {
    if (mBuffer == null) {
        mBuffer = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        mCanvas = Canvas(mBuffer!!)
        invalidateAllKeys()
    }
// the rest of the draw function ...
```

Comment: Could there be a better way? This approach looks like too much work and involves modifying a lot private vars/methods which could easily break in future Android versions. Might as well go through route of using images through "keyIcon" as it appears to be the cleaner way?

Comment: @paul_sns I wished there was a better way but now I am used to it. I haven't seen too much change in newer versions.

Comment: could you extend the answer please? I quite don't get how the onDraw would help change the font.

Comment: @Heidar can u share a sample project where u have used this method to overcome the issue

Comment: @Heidar please elaborate answer

Comment: @nutella_eater the answer is updated to the last version of my code

Answer (score 4):

One solution is to use [keboardView.java](http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/android/core/java/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.java.shtml) instead of `android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView`.

You also need to change `paint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD)` to `paint.setTypeface(my font)` and you must add [attrs.xml](http://code.google.com/p/softkeyboard/source/browse/branches/theme-support/SampleASKTheme/res/values/attrs.xml?spec=svn942&r=942) to your project.

Comment: how do i  add attrs.xml

Answer (score 2):

if you are thinking to change the font style of android custom keyboard keys font style with an external .ttf font style then you can check my answer at a link
[answer to change the font style of key label of android custom keyboard and also to change the font style throughout the android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31302666/can-you-change-the-android-keyboard-text-font-pragmatically/34355265#34355265)

this answer is verified by me personally so you can trust and check this.

Answer (score 0):

Well that's a very broad question. I can tell you how to set a different Typeface; how you work that into your keyboard application is up to you.

Place a font (.ttf or .otf) into your assets folder, and use the following code (assuming a font called "myfont.ttf" and a TextView with an id of "key"):

```
Typeface myFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "myfont.ttf");
TextView key = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.key);
key.setTypeface(myFont);
```

Reminder: Don't forget to check the license for the font you are using. Most do not allow redistribution without compensation. One freely licensed font you can use is Bitstream Vera Sans.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I am changing SoftKeyboard sample and I don't have any TextView to set Typeface to it. I just have an InputMethodService, a Keyboard, a Key and a KeyboardView.

Comment: Interesting. Yeah, looking into it more, I don't *see* a way to modify it. However, apps like SwiftKey have a different typeface for their keys, so it's possible. Unfortunately I don't have a better answer for you.

Comment: One solution is to place an image for each key, but it's time consuming. Thank you anyway and please tell me if you found anything.