# How to draw shift letter on keyboard in android?

Tags: android, keyboard

Hello
How can I draw shift letter at the corner of a key on keyboard?
I am changing SoftKeyboard sample.
Thank you.

Comment: Is shift a letter? Just kidding... take a look at the XML files in the res/xml directory ;)

Comment: Oh I mean how to draw 2 letters on one key, the main character of the key and the shifted character at the corner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by drawing the keyboard from scratch as I mentioned in this thread:
[How to change android keyboard key font?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808468/how-to-change-android-keyboard-key-font/4949412#4949412)