# How to change the default keyboard keys font

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

Don't mark the question as duplicate,cause i have looked for other questions and the answer looked incomplete to me.

There is a similar question: [How to change android keyboard key font?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808468/how-to-change-android-keyboard-key-font)

and one of it's answer is like :

> One solution is to use keboardView.java instead of android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.
> You also need to change paint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD) to paint.setTypeface(my font) and you must add attrs.xml to your project.

i have tried to set the paint.setTypeface which only changes the icons fonts which i have just drawn

## OnDraw

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        paint.setTextSize(25);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        
        Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Thin.ttf");
        
        paint.setTypeface(custom_font);
        
        
        List<Key> keys = getKeyboard().getKeys();
        
        
        for(Key key: keys) {
            if(key.label != null)
            {
                
            if(key.label.toString().equals("q") || key.label.toString().equals("Q") )   
                canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(1), key.x + (key.width/2)+10, key.y + 25, paint);
              
            else if(key.label.toString().equals("w") || key.label.toString().equals("W") )  
                canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(2), key.x + (key.width/2)+10, key.y + 25, paint);
            
            else if(key.label.toString().equals("e") || key.label.toString().equals("E") )  
                canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(3), key.x + (key.width/2)+10, key.y + 25, paint);
            
            else if(key.label.toString().equals("r") || key.label.toString().equals("R") )  
                canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(4), key.x + (key.width/2)+10, key.y + 25, paint);
             
            else if(key.label.toString().equals("t") || key.label.toString().equals("T") )  
                canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(5), key.x + (key.width/2)+10, key.y + 25, paint);
            
            else if(key.label.toString().equals("y") || key.label.toString().equals("Y") )  
                canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(6), key.x + (key.width/2)+10, key.y + 25, paint);
            
            else if(key.label.toString().equals("u") || key.label.toString().equals("U") )  
                canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(7), key.x + (key.width/2)+10, key.y + 25, paint);
            
            else if(key.label.toString().equals("i") || key.label.toString().equals("I") )  
                canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(8), key.x + (key.width/2)+10, key.y + 25, paint);
            
            else if(key.label.toString().equals("o") || key.label.toString().equals("o") )  
                canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(9), key.x + (key.width/2)+10, key.y + 25, paint);
            
            else if(key.label.toString().equals("p") || key.label.toString().equals("P") )  
                canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(0), key.x + (key.width/2)+10, key.y + 25, paint);
```

what am i missing to change the font style of custom keyboard.............

## update

if i imply these functions:

```
 @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        try{
        onBufferDraw();
        }catch(Exception ex){
    
        }
        if (mBuffer!=null)
            canvas.drawBitmap(mBuffer, 0, 0, null);
    }
```

which is actually retrieved from this link: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/a9de346/core/java/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.java

what are the things that i need to adjust..... cause the code looks long and many variables are also involved!!

## update

i have tried to implement onBufferDraw() in my Mykeyboardview class:

```
public class MyKeyboardView extends KeyboardView {
  
    private boolean caps = false;
    private Keyboard keyboard;
    

     private static final boolean DEBUG = false;
        private static final int NOT_A_KEY = -1;
        private static final int[] KEY_DELETE = { Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE };
        private static final int[] LONG_PRESSABLE_STATE_SET = { R.attr.state_long_pressable };   
        
        private Keyboard mKeyboard;
        private int mCurrentKeyIndex = NOT_A_KEY;
        private int mLabelTextSize;
        private int mKeyTextSize;
        private int mKeyTextColor;
        private float mShadowRadius;
        private int mShadowColor;
        private float mBackgroundDimAmount;
        
        private TextView mPreviewText;
        private PopupWindow mPreviewPopup;
        private int mPreviewTextSizeLarge;
        private int mPreviewOffset;
        private int mPreviewHeight;
        // Working variable
        private final int[] mCoordinates = new int[2];
        private PopupWindow mPopupKeyboard;
        private View mMiniKeyboardContainer;
        private KeyboardView mMiniKeyboard;
        private boolean mMiniKeyboardOnScreen;
        private View mPopupParent;
        private int mMiniKeyboardOffsetX;
        private int mMiniKeyboardOffsetY;
        private Map<Key,View> mMiniKeyboardCache;
        private Key[] mKeys;
        /** Listener for {@link OnKeyboardActionListener}. */
        private OnKeyboardActionListener mKeyboardActionListener;
        
        private static final int MSG_SHOW_PREVIEW = 1;
        private static final int MSG_REMOVE_PREVIEW = 2;
        private static final int MSG_REPEAT = 3;
        private static final int MSG_LONGPRESS = 4;
        private static final int DELAY_BEFORE_PREVIEW = 0;
        private static final int DELAY_AFTER_PREVIEW = 70;
        private static final int DEBOUNCE_TIME = 70;
        
        private int mVerticalCorrection;
        private int mProximityThreshold;
        private boolean mPreviewCentered = false;
        private boolean mShowPreview = true;
        private boolean mShowTouchPoints = true;
        private int mPopupPreviewX;
        private int mPopupPreviewY;
        private int mLastX;
        private int mLastY;
        private int mStartX;
        private int mStartY;
        private boolean mProximityCorrectOn;
        
        private Paint mPaint;
        private Rect mPadding;
        
        private long mDownTime;
        private long mLastMoveTime;
        private int mLastKey;
        private int mLastCodeX;
        private int mLastCodeY;
        private int mCurrentKey = NOT_A_KEY;
        private int mDownKey = NOT_A_KEY;
        private long mLastKeyTime;
        private long mCurrentKeyTime;
        private int[] mKeyIndices = new int[12];
        private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
        private int mPopupX;
        private int mPopupY;
        private int mRepeatKeyIndex = NOT_A_KEY;
        private int mPopupLayout;
        private boolean mAbortKey;
        private Key mInvalidatedKey;
        private Rect mClipRegion = new Rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
        private boolean mPossiblePoly;
      
        private int mSwipeThreshold;
        private boolean mDisambiguateSwipe;
        // Variables for dealing with multiple pointers
        private int mOldPointerCount = 1;
        private float mOldPointerX;
        private float mOldPointerY;
        private Drawable mKeyBackground;
        private static final int REPEAT_INTERVAL = 50; // ~20 keys per second
        private static final int REPEAT_START_DELAY = 400;
       
        private static int MAX_NEARBY_KEYS = 12;
        private int[] mDistances = new int[MAX_NEARBY_KEYS];
        // For multi-tap
        private int mLastSentIndex;
        private int mTapCount;
        private long mLastTapTime;
        private boolean mInMultiTap;
        private static final int MULTITAP_INTERVAL = 800; // milliseconds
        private StringBuilder mPreviewLabel = new StringBuilder(1);
        /** Whether the keyboard bitmap needs to be redrawn before it's blitted. **/
        private boolean mDrawPending;
        /** The dirty region in the keyboard bitmap */
        private Rect mDirtyRect = new Rect();
        /** The keyboard bitmap for faster updates */
        private Bitmap mBuffer;
        /** Notes if the keyboard just changed, so that we could possibly reallocate the mBuffer. */
        private boolean mKeyboardChanged;
        /** The canvas for the above mutable keyboard bitmap */
        private Canvas mCanvas;
       
    
    
    
    public MyKeyboardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
         
    }

    
    
    
    public void _setKeyboard(Keyboard kv)
    {
        this.keyboard=kv;
        
        
        
    }
    
    
     public MyKeyboardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
            TypedArray a =
                context.obtainStyledAttributes(
                    attrs, R.styleable.KeyboardView, defStyle, 0);
            LayoutInflater inflate =
                    (LayoutInflater) context
                            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            int previewLayout = 0;
            int keyTextSize = 0;
            int n = a.getIndexCount();
            
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                int attr = a.getIndex(i);
                switch (attr) {
                case R.styleable.KeyboardView_keyBackground:
                    mKeyBackground = a.getDrawable(attr);
                    break;
                case R.styleable.KeyboardView_verticalCorrection:
                    mVerticalCorrection = a.getDimensionPixelOffset(attr, 0);
                    break;
                case R.styleable.KeyboardView_keyPreviewLayout:
                    previewLayout = a.getResourceId(attr, 0);
                    break;
                case R.styleable.KeyboardView_keyPreviewOffset:
                    mPreviewOffset = a.getDimensionPixelOffset(attr, 0);
                    break;
                case R.styleable.KeyboardView_keyPreviewHeight:
                    mPreviewHeight = a.getDimensionPixelSize(attr, 80);
                    break;
                case R.styleable.KeyboardView_keyTextSize:
                    mKeyTextSize = a.getDimensionPixelSize(attr, 18);
                    break;
                case R.styleable.KeyboardView_keyTextColor:
                    mKeyTextColor = a.getColor(attr, 0xFF000000);
                    break;
                case R.styleable.KeyboardView_labelTextSize:
                    mLabelTextSize = a.getDimensionPixelSize(attr, 14);
                    break;
                case R.styleable.KeyboardView_popupLayout:
                    mPopupLayout = a.getResourceId(attr, 0);
                    break;
                case R.styleable.KeyboardView_shadowColor:
                    mShadowColor = a.getColor(attr, 0);
                    break;
                case R.styleable.KeyboardView_shadowRadius:
                    mShadowRadius = a.getFloat(attr, 0f);
                    break;
                }
            }
            
           // a = mContext.obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Theme);
            mBackgroundDimAmount = a.getFloat(R.styleable.Theme_backgroundDimAmount, 0.5f);
            mPreviewPopup = new PopupWindow(context);
            if (previewLayout != 0) {
                mPreviewText = (TextView) inflate.inflate(previewLayout, null);
                mPreviewTextSizeLarge = (int) mPreviewText.getTextSize();
                mPreviewPopup.setContentView(mPreviewText);
                mPreviewPopup.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
            } else {
                mShowPreview = false;
            }
            
            mPreviewPopup.setTouchable(false);
            
            mPopupKeyboard = new PopupWindow(context);
            mPopupKeyboard.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
            //mPopupKeyboard.setClippingEnabled(false);
            
            mPopupParent = this;
            //mPredicting = true;
            
            mPaint = new Paint();
            mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            mPaint.setTextSize(keyTextSize);
            mPaint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
            mPaint.setAlpha(255);
            mPadding = new Rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
            mMiniKeyboardCache = new HashMap<Key,View>();
            mKeyBackground.getPadding(mPadding);
            mSwipeThreshold = (int) (500 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
            
        }
    
    
    
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if (mDrawPending || mBuffer == null || mKeyboardChanged) {
            onBufferDraw();
        }
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBuffer, 0, 0, null);
        
        
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        paint.setTextSize(25);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        
        Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf");
        
        paint.setTypeface(custom_font);
        
        
        
        
        List<Key> keys = getKeyboard().getKeys();
        
        
        for(Key key: keys) {
            
            
            
            
            if(key.label != null)
            {
                
            if(key.label.toString().equals("q") || key.label.toString().equals("Q") )   
                canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(1), key.x + (key.width/2)+10, key.y + 25, paint);
              
            else if(key.label.toString().equals("w") || key.label.toString().equals("W") )  
                canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(2), key.x + (key.width/2)+10, key.y + 25, paint);
            
            else if(key.label.toString().equals("e") || key.label.toString().equals("E") )  
                canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(3), key.x + (key.width/2)+10, key.y + 25, paint);
            
            else if(key.label.toString().equals("r") || key.label.toString().equals("R") )  
                canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(4), key.x + (key.width/2)+10, key.y + 25, paint);
             
            else if(key.label.toString().equals("t") || key.label.toString().equals("T") )  
                canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(5), key.x + (key.width/2)+10, key.y + 25, paint);
            
            else if(key.label.toString().equals("y") || key.label.toString().equals("Y") )  
                canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(6), key.x + (key.width/2)+10, key.y + 25, paint);
            
            else if(key.label.toString().equals("u") || key.label.toString().equals("U") )  
                canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(7), key.x + (key.width/2)+10, key.y + 25, paint);
            
            else if(key.label.toString().equals("i") || key.label.toString().equals("I") )  
                canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(8), key.x + (key.width/2)+10, key.y + 25, paint);
            
            else if(key.label.toString().equals("o") || key.label.toString().equals("o") )  
                canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(9), key.x + (key.width/2)+10, key.y + 25, paint);
            
            else if(key.label.toString().equals("p") || key.label.toString().equals("P") )  
                canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(0), key.x + (key.width/2)+10, key.y + 25, paint);
            else
            {
                
                
                    
                    
            }
                
                
                 
                
                
            }
            
            
           
            
       }
    }


    
    private void onBufferDraw() {
        if (mBuffer == null || mKeyboardChanged) {
            if (mBuffer == null || mKeyboardChanged &&
                    (mBuffer.getWidth() != getWidth() || mBuffer.getHeight() != getHeight())) {
                // Make sure our bitmap is at least 1x1
                final int width = Math.max(1, getWidth());
                final int height = Math.max(1, getHeight());
                mBuffer = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                mCanvas = new Canvas(mBuffer);
            }
            invalidateAllKeys();
            mKeyboardChanged = false;
        }
        final Canvas canvas = mCanvas;
        canvas.clipRect(mDirtyRect, Op.REPLACE);
        
        if (mKeyboard == null) return;
        
        final Paint paint = mPaint;
        final Drawable keyBackground = mKeyBackground;
        final Rect clipRegion = mClipRegion;
        final Rect padding = mPadding;
        
        final Key[] keys = mKeys;
        final Key invalidKey = mInvalidatedKey;
        paint.setColor(mKeyTextColor);
        boolean drawSingleKey = false;
        
        
        final int keyCount = keys.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < keyCount; i++) {
            final Key key = keys[i];
            if (drawSingleKey && invalidKey != key) {
                continue;
            }
            int[] drawableState = key.getCurrentDrawableState();
            keyBackground.setState(drawableState);
            // Switch the character to uppercase if shift is pressed
            String label = key.label == null? null : adjustCase(key.label).toString();
            
            final Rect bounds = keyBackground.getBounds();
            if (key.width != bounds.right || 
                    key.height != bounds.bottom) {
                keyBackground.setBounds(0, 0, key.width, key.height);
            }
            
            keyBackground.draw(canvas);
            Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf");
            if (label != null) {
                // For characters, use large font. For labels like "Done", use small font.
                if (label.length() > 1 && key.codes.length < 2) {
                    paint.setTextSize(mLabelTextSize);
                    paint.setTypeface(custom_font);
                } else {
                    paint.setTextSize(mKeyTextSize);
                    paint.setTypeface(custom_font);
                }
                // Draw a drop shadow for the text
                paint.setShadowLayer(mShadowRadius, 0, 0, mShadowColor);
                // Draw the text
                canvas.drawText(label,
                    (key.width - padding.left - padding.right) / 2
                            + padding.left,
                    (key.height - padding.top - padding.bottom) / 2
                            + (paint.getTextSize() - paint.descent()) / 2 + padding.top,
                    paint);
                // Turn off drop shadow
                paint.setShadowLayer(0, 0, 0, 0);
            } else if (key.icon != null) {
                final int drawableX = (key.width - padding.left - padding.right 
                                - key.icon.getIntrinsicWidth()) / 2 + padding.left;
                final int drawableY = (key.height - padding.top - padding.bottom 
                        - key.icon.getIntrinsicHeight()) / 2 + padding.top;
                canvas.translate(drawableX, drawableY);
                key.icon.setBounds(0, 0, 
                        key.icon.getIntrinsicWidth(), key.icon.getIntrinsicHeight());
                key.icon.draw(canvas);
                canvas.translate(-drawableX, -drawableY);
            }
                  }
        mInvalidatedKey = null;
        // Overlay a dark rectangle to dim the keyboard
        if (mMiniKeyboardOnScreen) {
            paint.setColor((int) (mBackgroundDimAmount * 0xFF) << 24);
            canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), paint);
        }
        if (DEBUG && mShowTouchPoints) {
            paint.setAlpha(128);
            paint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
            canvas.drawCircle(mStartX, mStartY, 3, paint);
            canvas.drawLine(mStartX, mStartY, mLastX, mLastY, paint);
            paint.setColor(0xFF0000FF);
            canvas.drawCircle(mLastX, mLastY, 3, paint);
            paint.setColor(0xFF00FF00);
            canvas.drawCircle((mStartX + mLastX) / 2, (mStartY + mLastY) / 2, 2, paint);
        }
        
        mDrawPending = false;
        mDirtyRect.setEmpty();
    }

    
    private CharSequence adjustCase(CharSequence label) {
        if (mKeyboard.isShifted() && label != null && label.length() < 3
                && Character.isLowerCase(label.charAt(0))) {
            label = label.toString().toUpperCase();
        }
        return label;
    }
```

also included attrs.xml in my res/values

but nothing really happened in my code.... font style was not even changed but onBuffer was called i tested it with log print.

Answer (score 0):

Use this on your KeyboardView class.

```
@Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "yourfont.ttf");
    List<Keyboard.Key> keys = getKeyboard().getKeys();
    for (Keyboard.Key key : keys) {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setTypeface(tf);
        canvas.drawText(key.label.toString(), key.x + key.width,
                        key.y + key.height, paint);
    }
}
```

Comment: but it will draw new characters in the keys and won't change the font of the default one's....... @septemberboy7