# How to display Custom font on the onScreenKeyboardof the android device?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I want to change the onscreen keyboard according to the font .ttf file in my assets folder. I searched a lot but it always change the text which we typed but thier is no way i found to change the display of the onScreen Keyboard.
Please any body knows how to do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: U have to create custom keyboard http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808468/how-to-change-android-keyboard-key-font

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check my answer in this below link. This method will change the font style of your android application and as the keyboard is also in an android application of service so the font of the keyboard is also changed.
[This answer is verified and i have used this trick even i was searching of the same from a long time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31302666/can-you-change-the-android-keyboard-text-font-pragmatically/34355265#34355265)